# Could not find com.facebook.fresco:stetho:2.2.0 getting this error while running a newly created app. I'm totally struck at this issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, new-project

*** What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.facebook.fresco:stetho:2.2.0.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - file:/D:/React/Projects/node_modules/react-native/android/com/facebook/fresco/stetho/2.2.0/stetho-2.2.0.pom
> - file:/D:/React/Projects/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/facebook/fresco/stetho/2.2.0/stetho-2.2.0.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/facebook/fresco/stetho/2.2.0/stetho-2.2.0.pom
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/facebook/fresco/stetho/2.2.0/stetho-2.2.0.pom
> - https://www.jitpack.io/com/facebook/fresco/stetho/2.2.0/stetho-2.2.0.pom
> Required by:
> project :app > com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:0.75.1**

> `npx react-native info`

```
info Fetching system and libraries information...
System:
OS: Windows 10 10.0.22000
CPU: (16) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10870H CPU @ 2.20GHz
Memory: 3.47 GB / 15.78 GB
Binaries:
Node: 16.13.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
Yarn: Not Found
npm: 8.1.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
Watchman: Not Found
SDKs:
Android SDK: Not Found
Windows SDK: Not Found
IDEs:
Android Studio: Not Found
Visual Studio: Not Found
Languages:
Java: 18.0.1.1 - C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\javac.EXE
npmPackages:
@react-native-community/cli: Not Found
react: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2 
react-native: 0.68.2 => 0.68.2 
react-native-windows: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
*react-native*: Not Found
```

Comment: hi, did you manage to solve this issue?.. i am getting same error, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Updating FLIPPER_VERSION inside android/gradle.properties fixed this problem for me:

```
# Version of flipper SDK to use with 
React Native FLIPPER_VERSION=0.99.0
```

Credit to:
https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/2683#issuecomment-944085698